# query in Server Management Studio + table in ssrs reports+-using select with correlated sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, dynamics-crm, aggregate-functions

i have a table, consist fruit groups and sizes
i.e:

```
                          send         send
**fruit-package  /  size  /  start-date/   end-date/ **  
-------------------------------------------------- 
apple          s           2.2.16            5.2.16
apple          s           7.2.16          **10.2.16**
apple          s          **20.2.16**         21.2.16
--------------------------------------------------
apple          l             1.2.16       **5.2.16**
apple          l            **25.2.16**     26.2.16
apple          l            26.2.16        27.2.16
-------------------------------------------------
orange         m               1.1.16       2.1.16     
orange         m               3.1.16       **4.1.16**
orange         m              **24.1.16**    25.1.16
---------------------------------------------------
```

i need , for each specific group of fruit-package and size
(like apple+small), to find the **max** days,in the group, passed between 
one package send-end-date to the followed package, in the group ,send-start-day
and then select that send-end-date and follow start date and calculate 
that max diff between these two values, and put them in the result table for that specific group, doing it for each group

**so the result table would be**

```
                             send         send
**fruit-package /   size  /  start-date /  end-date/ **  
-------------------------------------------------- 
apple               s      20.2.16     10.2.16                      
--------------------------------------------------                            

apple               l      25.2.16     5.2.16
-------------------------------------------------
orange              m      24.1.16     4.1.16

---------------------------------------------------
```

**i tried to do this in parts.
first part:**
 for each group of fruit -
find all combination of:

(fruit-package) + (size) + (current end_date)  and the  start_date of the follow package
like that:

```
select P.fruit
,P.size
,P.end_date

,(SELECT top 1 (pa.start_date)
  FROM packages as pa 
  WHERE pa.start_date >= pa.end_date   
  and p.fruit=pa.fruit and p.size=pa.size
    order by pa.start_date desc  ) as start    


  into #temp

from packages p 


group by p.fruit
, P.size
,p.end_date
```

and second step would be, simplly find the row with the largest day-diff in each group

**but the first part i wrote won't work- got null value as start date,
or one end_date and not for each group from inside select -
why  and
how to  correct it?**

please help

**thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you if you have 2012 or later.

```
Create Table #Tbl (Name Varchar(8000), Size Char(1), StartDate Date, EndDate Date)
Insert #Tbl Values ('apple', 's', '2.2.16', '2.5.16')
Insert #Tbl Values ('apple', 's', '2.7.16', '2.10.16')
Insert #Tbl Values ('apple', 's', '2.20.16', '2.21.16')
Insert #Tbl Values ('apple', 'l', '2.1.16', '2.5.16')
Insert #Tbl Values ('apple', 'l', '2.25.16', '2.26.16')
Insert #Tbl Values ('apple', 'l', '2.26.16', '2.27.16')
Insert #Tbl Values ('orange', 'm', '1.1.16', '1.2.16') 
Insert #Tbl Values ('orange', 'm', '1.3.16', '1.4.16')
Insert #Tbl Values ('orange', 'm', '1.24.16', '1.25.16')

;With cteQry As
(
Select  *, 
        Lead(StartDate) Over (Partition By Name, Size Order By StartDate) NextStartDate,
         DateDiff(d, EndDate, Lead(StartDate) Over (Partition By Name, Size Order By StartDate)) Days
    From #Tbl
)
Select *
    From
        (
        Select  *,
                Row_Number() Over (Partition By Name, Size Order By Days Desc) SortOrder
            From cteQry
        ) A
    Where SortOrder = 1
```

EDIT:  Without lead function.

```
;With cteQry2 As
(
Select  *,
          DateDiff(d, EndDate, 
                (Select Top 1 StartDate 
                     From #Tbl 
                     Where Name = T1.Name 
                          And Size = T1.Size 
                          And StartDate > T1.StartDate 
                     Order By StartDate)) Days
     From #Tbl T1
)
Select *
    From
        (
        Select  *,
                Row_Number() Over (Partition By Name, Size Order By Days Desc) SortOrder
            From cteQry2
        ) A
    Where SortOrder = 1
     Order By Name, Size, StartDate
```

Comment: beautiful answer , thank you very much!! :),                                                 but i check and it's appear to be i won't be allowed to use sql 2012, it won't be correlate with the whole system,so i don't have the Lead() function, could you please help rewrite it to fit to sql 2008?  thanks a lot!!

Comment: I added a query that does not use the lead function so should work for you on 2008.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a lot:),     you are the best!